# Exporting a tank track belt as an .stl for 3D printing

Tags: modifiers, export, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make a 3D printable tank model, and have made a set of tracks for it using [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfnfwrmMfJc) Unfortunately I can't seem to work out how to export the track links as an .stl so I can easily print them! I wanted the tracks and running gear/wheels/suspension etc to be printed as a single piece (they're not going to be workable as it's intended to be mostly a static model, and having the running gear being printed as one piece for each side of the hull seemed like a sensible solution for ease of printing/assembly) but I cannot export them properly; it keeps exporting the plane array but not the instanced links? I've tried applying modifiers and it makes no difference whatsoever.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

If it helps, here's a pic of the model so far:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out to anyone with a similar problem, I just had to go to Objects/Apply/"Make Instances Real".